# Can't Log Into Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gnome, login-screen, guest-session

Yesterday, after turning on Ubuntu, I logged into a Gnome session. A few minutes later, I tried switching to Unity for a change. Unfortunately,  the background and my desktop icons loaded, but the system bar and launcher failed to load even after several minutes. Unity had always worked fine for me.

I then tried the guest account, and it worked fine on both Unity and Gnome. However, the problem with my account got worse; I couldn't log into any desktop at all anymore. I would type in my password and press enter and it would just sit there doing nothing. The computer no longer responded in any way, so I had to hold the power button and reboot. The same problem happened repeatedly.

Earlier today, I tried to get on again. I found that I hadthe same problem, when I tried to log in, the computer no longer locked up, but instead flashed a black screen with theconsole output and what seemed to be an error message before returning to the log in screen. It was to quick for me to read, about 1/4-1/2 second.

I'd really appreciate some help as I have some important files that are not backed up yet. I can't transfer the files to a new account, or even make a new account because I tried taking the password off my account so now I can't authenticate from the guest to perform root functions.

I'd really appreciate some help as I have some important files that are not backed up yet. Thanks.

Comment: Try creating a new user account and log into Gnome and Unity to see if both work ok. If so, the problem is with your user.

Comment: I can't create a new user because my account, the admin, has no password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get in your account from the terminal *without GUI* and back up the files or fix some issues from there.

Hit Ctrl+Alt+F1, and you'll see a login prompt. Log in and do your stuff, from the command line.

You can create a new user from the command line like this:

```
sudo adduser <newusername>
```

If you want to get back to GUI desktop, hit Ctrl+Alt+F7.

Comment: I found out I have the files I need in Ubuntu One. So I'm reinstalling. This did help me make some progress and I think would have worked though, so thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue.  The problem was in the user .XAuthority file permission was owned by the root user.  I changed the file permission and was able to log back in.